# Quintus getting first sprite displayed - very simple

Tags: javascript

I've written some code based on Quintus which I believe should display a ball on a canvas ... but it doesn't !

Would be grateful if anyone could point out the problem. I've adapted the code from a couple of different sources and that's probably the problem.

The code is below but just a couple of things:

- the request for ball.png completes successfully with a 200;
- the javascript console shows no errors
- the canvas is visible but the ball.png is not

So here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // Wait for the window to finish loading

var Q = window.Q = Quintus()                // Create a new engine instance
    .include("Sprites, Scenes, Input, 2D, Anim, Touch, UI") // Load any needed modules
    .setup("myGame")                        // Bind Quintus to the canvas with ID "myGame"
    .controls()                             // Add in default controls (keyboard, buttons)
    .touch();                               // Add in touch support (for the UI)

    /*
    ... Actual game code goes here ...
    */
    Q.Sprite.extend("Ball",{
      init:function(p) {
        this._super(p,{
          asset: "ball.png",
          x: 0,
          y: 300,
          vx: 50,
          vy: -400
        });
      },

      step: function(dt) {
        this.p.vy += dt * 9.8;

        this.p.x += this.p.vx * dt;
        this.p.y += this.p.vy * dt;
      }
    });

    Q.load(["ball.png"],function() {
      var ball = new Q.Ball();
      Q.gameLoop(function(dt) {
        ball.update(dt);
        Q.clear();
        ball.render(Q.ctx);
      });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

When I tried your code, it gave me no errors because for some reason the window load event was not being triggered. Not sure why on that part, but I managed to fix that by not waiting for the window to load (remove the first line and last line in your code).

After doing that, I ran into some errors in the console, namely that there is a function in quintus_sprites attempting to access a property of an undefined. The property that quintus_sprites was trying to access was obj.p.points.length in the Q._generateCollisionPoints function, but obj.p.points was undefined (you never defined it in your Ball init function, and you never inserted the sprite into a stage - at which point only would Quintus help to generate the points based on the sprite's asset). I managed to fix this by setting an arbitrary array of points in the sprite's init function.

Here's the code that works for me after making the above fixes:

```
var Q = window.Q = Quintus()                // Create a new engine instance
.include("Sprites, Scenes, Input, 2D, Anim, Touch, UI") // Load any needed modules
.setup("myGame")                        // Bind Quintus to the canvas with ID "myGame"
.controls()                             // Add in default controls (keyboard, buttons)
.touch();                               // Add in touch support (for the UI)

/*
... Actual game code goes here ...
*/
Q.Sprite.extend("Ball",{
    init:function(p) {
        this._super(p,{
            asset: "ball.png",
            points: [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1]],
            x: 0,
            y: 300,
            vx: 50,
            vy: -400
        });
    },

    step: function(dt) {
        this.p.vy += dt * 9.8;

        this.p.x += this.p.vx * dt;
        this.p.y += this.p.vy * dt;
    }
});

Q.load("ball.png",function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
    var ball = new Q.Ball();
    Q.gameLoop(function(dt) {
        ball.update(dt);
        Q.clear();
        ball.render(Q.ctx);
    });
});
```